# IOS native Google ads are plugged in and can display properly on wifi, but switching to 4g won't show ads

Tags: ios

Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=13 "Request Error: Received invalid response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: Received invalid response., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: Received invalid response.}

Comment: I just searched up that error code, which took me here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/vOKVCJ7bjvw . It mentions changing the `info.plist` to allow requests by changing the `AppTransportSecurity` settings.

Comment: I've added AppTransportSecurity to info.plist, but it still shows an error

Comment: Can you provide more information then? How do you configure your ads (code)? If your running the app on your device, check if 'Use mobile data' is allowed for the app.